# the error about transplantation VXL to android

Tags: android, cmake

I want to transplant the VXL(the Vision-something-Libraries) to android platform.the crosscompiler I used is  android-cmake.
you can get the VXL from the url http://vxl.sourceforge.net/  .the version i used is vxl-1.14.0
you can get the android-camke from the url http://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/

when I properly setup my NDK for cmake,and specify the Standalone Toolchain  as the introduction of android-camke.Then,I use andriod-camke to compile the VXL.But I encounter many error.it can't produce the Makefile . somebody know why?

Next is the error log.

```
l00138375@l00138375:/home/hm/build-vxl$ android-cmake ../vxl-1.14.0
CMake Warning at /home/hm/android/android-cmake/toolchain/android.toolchain.cmake:281 (message):
  Using value of obsolete variable ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT as initial
  value for ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN.  Please note, that
  ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT can be completely removed in future versions of
  the toolchain.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/hm/android/android-cmake/toolchain/android.toolchain.cmake:376 (__INIT_VARIABLE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:89 (INCLUDE)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (PROJECT)

........

-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Performing Test VCL_CHAR_IS_SIGNED
CMake Error: TRY_RUN() invoked in cross-compiling mode, please set the following cache variables appropriately:
   VCL_CHAR_IS_SIGNED (advanced)
   VCL_CHAR_IS_SIGNED__TRYRUN_OUTPUT (advanced)
For details see /home/hm/build-vxl/TryRunResults.cmake
-- Performing Test VCL_CHAR_IS_SIGNED - Failed
-- Looking for 8-bit int. [Checking char...]
CMake Error: TRY_RUN() invoked in cross-compiling mode, please set the following cache variables appropriately:
   RUN_RESULT (advanced)
   RUN_RESULT__TRYRUN_OUTPUT (advanced)
For details see /home/hm/build-vxl/TryRunResults.cmake
.........
-- Performing Test VCL_NUMERIC_LIMITS_HAS_INFINITY
CMake Error: TRY_RUN() invoked in cross-compiling mode, please set the following cache variables appropriately:
   VCL_NUMERIC_LIMITS_HAS_INFINITY (advanced)
   VCL_NUMERIC_LIMITS_HAS_INFINITY__TRYRUN_OUTPUT (advanced)
For details see /home/hm/build-vxl/TryRunResults.cmake
-- Performing Test VCL_NUMERIC_LIMITS_HAS_INFINITY - Failed
-- Performing Test VCL_PROCESSOR_HAS_INFINITY
CMake Error: TRY_RUN() invoked in cross-compiling mode, please set the following cache variables appropriately:
   VCL_PROCESSOR_HAS_INFINITY (advanced)
   VCL_PROCESSOR_HAS_INFINITY__TRYRUN_OUTPUT (advanced)
For details see /home/hm/build-vxl/TryRunResults.cmake
-- Performing Test VCL_PROCESSOR_HAS_INFINITY - Failed
-- Looking for C++ include inttypes.h
-- Looking for C++ include inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for memalign
-- Looking for memalign - found
-- Could NOT find DC1394 (missing:  DC1394_LIBRARIES DC1394_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Performing Test DIRECTSHOW_SOURCE_COMPILES
-- Performing Test DIRECTSHOW_SOURCE_COMPILES - Failed
CMake Error at config/cmake/Modules/NewCMake/FindDirectShow.cmake:101 (MESSAGE):
  Uncomment code below: FindPackageHandleStandardArgs is now available.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  core/vidl/CMakeLists.txt:13 (INCLUDE)
```

Comment: There are no real errors in cmake output. All errors are the default behavior of the `TRY_RUN` cmake command in case of cross-compiling (it is not possible to run cross-compiled program on the host platform)

Comment: Do your meaning is that I can't transplant the vxl to android?

Answer (score 1):

As Andrey's comment mentions, the way VXL uses CMake, prevents cross-compilation. However there is an alternative. One of the maintainers maintains branches containing alternative build systems for the core libraries. The `vxl-build-makefiles` branch ought to be a good starting point to modify to work with a cross-compiler.

http://sourceforge.net/p/vxl/svn/36716/tree/branches/vxl-build-makefiles/

If you have any questions about using the branch, or indeed anything else about VXL - the vxl mailing lists are probably more use. vxl-users@lists.sourceforge.net